# Thunderbird in 18.04: "Configuration could not be verified - is the username or password wrong?"

Tags: 18.04, password, thunderbird

Thunderbird worked well with Ubuntu 16.04. After changing to 18.04 and after re-installing Thunderbird again e.g. via terminal, the following problem arose:
Thunderbird does not accept user name and/or password, although these data are accepted without a problem by the web page of the provider t-online.
Message reads: "Configuration could not be verified - is the username or password wrong?"
Who can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you enable 2FA on your email account? If you enabled 2FA you need to recreate a new "app specified password" from your email provider ex. gmail

Comment: No, 2 Factor Authentication is not known to me.